# Solving $\ln y = 3t + 8$ for $y$

Tags: logarithms

Question:

> Solve for $y$.
>    $$\ln y = 3t + 8$$

I tried answering the question with $$(\ln x - 8)/3$$ but I am told it's wrong. I'm really confused with the logarithms unit, so any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you'd been solving for $t$, you would've been correct! :) (Well, except that you changed the $y$ to an $x$ for some reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one single trick  with logarithms: isolate a logarithm and exponentiate. In your case $\log y = 3t+8$ the logarithm is already isolated, so we exponentiate:
$$
e^{\log y} = e^{3t+8}
$$
but $e^{\log y} = y$, so $y = e^{3t+8}$.